# DartR - Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Tags: r

I am very much a novice with R and am attempting to run a script that will filter a set of SNPs for 6 populations. I've successfully run this script before but I'm getting a new error in the initial stages of the script.
I've not been able to find anything similar to my issue online, though a few have the same error. The error comes up when R is trying to read in the SNP data and the function and error are as follows from the console screen:

```
>FijiHomaGL <- gl.read.dart(filename = "genCSV_modified.csv", ind.metafile = "COV_file.csv",
+                            nas = "-",  topskip = 6, lastmetric = TRUE, probar = TRUE)
Starting gl.read.dart 
Starting utils.read.dart 
  Reading in the SNP data
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

[A screenshot of the .csv file I'm trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ83Y.png)
I'm not able to include the actual file but a screenshot is linked above for a general idea of the layout.

Any help is much appreciated I am very new so let me know if there is anything else I should include! Thanks in advance. The package being used for this function is dartR but I can't add it as a tag.

Comment: Hello @patriciaslattery. Welcome on SO! I think it would help if you would provide us with the structure of your csv file. What I understand from the error message is that your file contains some variable with  non-numeric data (which is not expected by the function)

Comment: Thankyou! I wasn't able to find a way to include the .csv file and I'm hesitant to put it online as it's not my own data, but I've attached a screenshot of what it looks like in R

Comment: O.K. I don't know the package you are using but it seems to me that the columns containing numbers are of type `character` and not `numeric` (looking closely at your screenshot, the numbers are on the left side of the columns when they should be justified on the right). Therefore, I think the solution is simply to convert the columns with numbers to `numeric` type.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice. I have tried only converting the columns with numbers to `numeric`, and then all the columns to be safe but both are still giving me the same error unfortunately